# (iphone) inAppPurchase when to log purchase history in own server?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'd like to record purchase history in my server.

Problem is,
I shouldn't log it until purchase is complete.(because the purchase might fail)
But if I log it after purchase's completion, user might stop the application and app might fail to send the purchase history message to server.

I originally thought "logging purchase history" when user verifies the receipt(when my server gets the verification of receipt from apple server).
But user might go through receipt verification stage several times without actually completing the purchase? (i'm not sure about this)

Is there a recommended way of storing in-app-purchase buy history in server model?

Comment: IF you are blocking the UI when user is making in app purchase, One solution is to update your server after the purchase is successfully done and only then enable the UI (by removing some overlay with activity indicator).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can temporarily persist the purchase log using `NSUserDefaults` upon purchase completion and sync it to server afterwards.
2. You can block the UI until purchase is completed AND the purchase log is pushed to server.

Comment: what about the home button to quit the app?

Comment: if you're using option-1 and user quits the app, your log will still be persisted in NSUserDefaults. It is not effected by termination of app.

Comment: Here is a simple tutorial for how to save/retrieve your data using NSUserDefaults: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Answer (score 0):

You should register to your own server before purchase transaction finishes

If the aplication becomes inactive, The "Transaction" retries the purchasing process when the application becomes active

For that you must use SKPaymentTransaction:

After `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];`

Save into your own server and if successfull

```
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = <# The current payment #>;
SKPaymentQueue *queue = [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue];

[defaultQueue finishTransaction:transaction;]
```

if not

```
[defaultQueue restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername
```